# return slice of empty interface from function

Tags: go

Can someone explain why this doesn't work and how can we return slices of interfaces, []interface{}, from functions like showed in the example?

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var test []string
    Test(&test)
    fmt.Println(test)
}

func Test(t interface{}) {
    a := []interface{}{"first", "second"}
    fmt.Println(a)
    t = a
}
```

Example of running code can be found here: 
https://play.golang.org/p/vcEGHSdWrjv

BTW, this is the `func` I'm trying to extract data from: https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo#Collection.Distinct

Note: the type we expect is not always of type `[]string`, I'm just using string as an example here.

Thanks!

Comment: Describe the higher-level problem that you are trying to solve.  For example, are you trying to copy a `[]interface{}` to a slice of any type, or something else?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here or trying to accomplish - the text asks "how can we return slices of interfaces ... like showed in the example", but the function in the example doesn't return anything at all, and it operates on `interface{}`, not `[]interface{}`.

Comment: @Erin it doesn't take a slice of type interface, it just takes an `interface{}`.

Comment: @ThunderCat higher-level use-case is to retrieve data from this function: https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo#Collection.Distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because an []string and a []interface{} are different types, you cannot assign one to the other.

You must copy the slice to convert []interface{} to a slice of some specific type. If you know that the []interface{} always contains string values, then use the following:

```
func stringSlice() []string {
    a := []interface{}{"first", "second"} // query result
    fmt.Println(a)

    result := make([]string, len(a))
    for i := range a {
       var ok bool
       result[i], ok = a[i].(string)
       if !ok {
          // handle error with unexpected type
       }
    }
    return result
}
```

If the result can have arbitrary element types, then use [reflection](https://godoc.org/reflect) to copy the slice:

```
func anySlice(result interface{}) {
    a := []interface{}{"first", "second"} // query result

    slice := reflect.ValueOf(result).Elem()
    elementType := slice.Type().Elem()
    for _, v := range a {
        rv := reflect.ValueOf(v)
        if !rv.Type().AssignableTo(elementType) {
            // handle error with unexpected type
        }
        slice.Set(reflect.Append(slice, rv))
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var s []string
anySlice(&s)
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/d83mbX7aDz6)

Comment: thank you for the reply, but no, the result may not always be a `[]string`, that's why the `func` uses an `[]interface{}` to return the query results

Answer (score 2):

In you example, you are not trying to "return" a slice but rather you seem to be looking to modify the argument to point to a new slice of strings.

The way you are doing it does not work cause in Go, arguments are passed by value.

When you do this:

```
t = a
```

`t` is a *copy* of the `&test` you are sending to the function as an argument.

So modifying `t` does not change your `test` variable.

You need to pass in the address of a pointer in order to be able to modify what the pointer points to.

Try this way:

```
func main() {
    var test *[]string
    Test(&test)
    fmt.Println(*test)
}

func Test(t interface{}) {
    a := []string{"first", "second"}
    fmt.Println(a)
    *t.(**[]string) = &a
}
```

Output:

```
[first second]
[first second]
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/tliMrmliykp

Comment: sorry about the semantics. when I say `return` in this context obviously means use parameters passed by pointers to "return" values to the caller.

I'm passing as argument the pointer to `t` so I would expect that to work the same as it works for any other var type.

the way you stated works. Thank you for pointing out that! But I still can't fully understand why it doesn't work the way I have in the example.

Comment: @n.p: you're not passing a pointer to the function, you're passing an interface value containing a pointer value. You're also assigning the new slice to the interface value only within the function scope, and even if that could work like you want, you would be assigning a `[]string` to an `[]interface{}` which is not valid.

Comment: @NelsonPina: it is because t is a copy.. I updated the answer to explain it better, let me know if it makes sense

Comment: @JimB I see, it's getting a bit clear for me now. I'm still wrapping my head around the empty interface type in Go. thank you for your clarifications. it still seems that it the syntax to achieve this is quite heavy though, I would expect something simpler. BTW, this is the function I'm trying to retrieve data from: https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo#Collection.Distinct

Comment: @eugenioy you are missing the point that the func uses `[]interface{}` for a reason. If the `a := []interface{}{"first", "second"}` was always of type `[]string` then I wouldn't need to pass an empty interface. in your reply you are assuming that the value we need to extract is always of type []string.